# Match exactly two backslashes

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to match exactly two `\` characters (first ones encountered going from the left) in a string via Powershell regexp -replace command, to replace them with `/`. Doing `\\{2}` doesn't work, as it only matches two backslashes together.. I've tried `\\.+?\\`, but that matches the whole substring between them.
I'm new to regexp, and nothing I found on various sites has helped me with this issue. And I know I can do that with a for loop that runs twice, but I'd first like to know if it could be done with regexp better.

EDIT: I'm looking to do something like this:
*IN*: `\aaa\bbb(d\c)`
*OUT*: `/aaa/bbb(d\c)`

Comment: What would be wrong with `\\\\\`?

Comment: Are you after [``$s -replace '\\([^\\]+)\\','/$1/'``](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5c%28%5b%5e%5c%5c%5d%2b%29%5c%5c&i=some%5ctext%5chere&r=%2f%241%2f)?

Comment: Please provide an example string with expected output.

Comment: @Tim`\\\` only selects two backslashes together, while @Wiktor's expression replaces the whole substring between them. This is not what I'm looking for,unfortunately.

Comment: You need exactly my solution. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Wiktor My bad, I used regex101.com to verify your solution, but I put the substitution argument wrong. Tested the whole command in powershell, works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @Jefrejtor Do not test .NET regexps at regex101, it does not support .NET regex. Only check if a solution works or not in the *target* environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
$s -replace '\\([^\\]+)\\','/$1/'
```

[image]

Here, `\\([^\\]+)\\` matches a `\`, then matches and captures any 1+ chars other than `\` into Group 1 (later access with `$1` from the replacement pattern) and then matches `\`, and replaces the match with `/`, the value in Group 1 and `/`.

To only replace the first occurrence, you may use

```
$s -replace '(?s)\\([^\\]+)\\(.*)','/$1/$2'
```

where the trailing `(.*)` will capture the rest of the string (if any) into Group 2 and the `$2` replacement backreference will paste that part of the string back into the result. `(?s)` will allow `.` to match line break chars that it does not match by default.